# How to write a conditional statement that chooses between three colors to produce a specific image

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm doing a lab for a Computer Science course I am taking in university. The problem states, "Have each return an int representation of a Color. Also have each accept four int parameters: a column index, a row index, an image width, and an image height. Eventually you will use these parameters to arbitrate between colors."

Specifically for the method I cannot figure out, the question is, "In method boxColor, write a conditional statement that chooses between three colors to produce this image".

This is the image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2nsH.png)

---

Just so it's clear what my professor is expecting here is a quick example of another problem that was assigned.

The question states, "In method stripesColor, write a conditional statement that chooses between three colors to produce this image:"

The image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jeRb.png)

And here is the code I wrote to complete the task:

```
  public static int stripesColor(int column, int row, int imWidth, int imHeight) {
      if (column < (imHeight / 3)) {
         return Color.red.getRGB();
      } else if ((column < 2 * (imHeight / 3))) {
         return Color.pink.getRGB();
      } else {
         return Color.orange.getRGB();
    }
  }
```

---

I should also mention just so it's clear, the professor provided us with a class that will use the methods we write to produce the images, we're only responsible to do the calculations in order to achieve the pictures he provides.

I have tried finding the diagonal of the entire square (512px x 512px) and making the smaller square on the inside 1/5 of the total size but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is just wrong or if there is another way to go about doing this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: By *chooses between 3 colours*, do you mean randomly choosing 3 colours?

Comment: The colors don't matter as long as they aren't the same. The colors can be hardcoding they don't need to be random no.

Comment: If it helps, here's the link to the lab assignment page. https://twodee.org/blog/17328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend breaking it down into smaller problems and handle them in isolation. Focus on just one case first, maybe the simplest one, and then tackle the others.

Just off the top of my head, don't hold me too much to the math...

```
public static int stripesColor(int column, int row, int imWidth, int imHeight) {
    // Just worry about the square in the center for now.

    // If pixel is not in left/bottom or top/right quarters:
    if (imWidth / 4 < column < (imWidth * 3)/4) && 
    (imHeight / 4 < row < (imHeight * 3)/4) {

        return Color.hotpink.getRGB();

    } else if {
        // We know that any pixel in the center square is already taken care of, 
        // so the logic for the rest can completely ignore that.
        // It can be written as though the square isn't in the image at all.
    } else {
        // Last remaining color
    }
}
```

I also don't know if the dims of the inner square are 1/2 or 3/5 of the total size; I assumed 1/2 here, but it shouldn't matter, ultimately. Hopefully this helps get you unstuck.

If the math inside the `if` condition looks gross, you can always initialize separate variables for those values, and then the condition will be much cleaner (and, basically, self-documenting).

Comment: Just to clarify, this method is referring to the first question in my post?

Comment: Yes it is. That’s the one you wanted us to focus on, right?

Comment: Ok, I got it all functioning thank you. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This is less a coding problem and more a problem of how to structure the combinational logic.

Let's break down the box.  The box is essentially composed of three pieces - a yellow triangle in the upper left half, a cyan triange in the lower right half, and a magenta square overlaid on top.

Ok.  Let look at the first part - how do we define the upper-left half of the image?
If we treat square image pixels as a graph, then the center line spliting yellow and cyan is the line the runs from the origin (0,0) to the upper-left corner (imWidth, imHeight).
This line has a slope of one and the form of y=x.  So a pixel in the upper-left corner is anywhere where the column <= row.

So we set the return value to the yellow integer value when column <= row.

For the lower-left coner we chose the opposite comparison, so we set the return value to the cyan integer value when column > row.

Now to handle the overlay, we want to find the cases where the pixel is within that central area.  Lets say we want the image to take up 80% of the middle, then we need to set buffer area to 10% of the total size.  So what we check for is whether or not (imWidth * (0.1) < row ) && (row < imWidth * (1-0.1)) && (imHeight * (0.1) < column) && (column < imHeight * (1-0.1))

```
public static int boxColor(int column, int row, int imWidth, int imHeight) {
    final int UPPER_LEFT_COLOR = 0; // Set to upper-left color.
    final int LOWER_RIGHT_COLOR = 128; // Set to lower-right color.
    final int CENTER_SQUARE_COLOR = 255; // Set to center color.
    final double MARGIN_AMOUNT = 0.1; // Set to buffer percentage

    int return_color = 0; //Initialize the return value to something.
    // First set the return value based on the midline split.
    if (column <= row) {
        return_color = UPPER_LEFT_COLOR;
    } else {
        return_color = LOWER_RIGHT_COLOR;
    }
    // Test for the overlay and reset the return value.
    if ((imWidth * (MARGIN_AMOUNT) < row ) && (row < imWidth * (1-MARGIN_AMOUNT)) && (imHeight * (MARGIN_AMOUNT) < column) && (column < imHeight * (1-MARGIN_AMOUNT))) {
        return_color = CENTER_SQUARE_COLOR;
    }
    // Return the finally determined value.
    return return_color;
}
```